# Add links to Vuetify tree-view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Im using vuetify's treeview component and I want the last child in each node to be a router link, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Even if I could just bind an @click event that would work for me.

I cannot see in the docs or examples how to do this.

This is what my component looks like:

```html
<template>
    <div>
       <v-treeview :items="items"></v-treeview>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'Parent',
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'Child1',
                            to:'booking' // <---I want to put a router link here or click event handler
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a scoped slot for your labels:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-treeview :items="items">
            <template slot="label" slot-scope="props">
                <router-link :to="props.item.to">{{ props.item.name }}</router-link>
            </template>
        </v-treeview>
    </div>
</template>
```

You should also make sure to display data that do not have the `to` property without a link. You can use a simple `v-if` for that:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-treeview :items="items">
            <template slot="label" slot-scope="props">
                <router-link :to="props.item.to" v-if="props.item.to">{{ props.item.name }}</router-link>
                <span v-else>{{ props.item.name }}</span>
            </template>
        </v-treeview>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks mate.

Comment: Im using this solution too, The thing is that at my nav menu where im using the treeview, I have to press on the link for the route to work, i want the route to work when i press anywhere within the row, You know how to achive that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it, it definitely seems like they should expose a click event on each item, but until then..

```
<template>
  <v-treeview
    :items="items"
    :active.sync="active"
    return-object
    activatable
    >
  </v-treeview>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    active: [],
    items: [],
  }),
  watch: {
    active (arr) {
      if (arr.length)
        this.onClick(arr[0])
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onClick (item) {
      console.log('click', item)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```